# is there any generic f# convent way to run background job

Tags: c#, f#

In c# the convenient way is to inherit from the BackgroundService class and register to the hosting framework with AddHostedService().

In f# is there any generic native way to do this? don't want to mix c# OO code style in f# fp code style

Comment: F# is pragmatic and it's fine to mix OOP with FP. You may use whatever approach you want. For example, sometimes is better to use iterative `for` instead of functional `let rec`, sometimes pure functional approach is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, so caveat emptor, but one way to avoid creating a class type is to use an [object expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/object-expressions) instead:

```ml
let service =
    {
        new BackgroundService() with
            override __.ExecuteAsync(_) =
                new Task(fun () -> printfn "Hello world")
    }
```

I think you can then register it like this:

```ml
services.AddHostedService(fun _ -> service)
```

Comment: thanks, it helps me to write code more clean and more fp way